# printing a string in c characer by character

Tags: c

i know , that my question is unusual behaviour for coding , but i just do it , to understand C language in deep , so i ask user to enter a string and i want to print this string character by character , before doing this , i save the string in memory , which it's address saved in 'x' , can i print this string character by character , by this way ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc ,char *argv[20])
{
    char x ;
    strcpy(&x,argv[1]);
    printf("%s and it's length is %d : \n" , &x , strlen(&x));
    int i ;

    for(i=0 ; i < strlen(&x) ; i++)
    {
        printf(" hi : %c\n" , x[i]);
        /* also i try '%x[i]' but it's give me another error
        so how i do this ??*/
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i have an important notes , first , the code is CORRECTLY work until it get the for loop !!

Comment: Again no. If you are so sure about your code, why ask here?. The first strcpy ist just plain wrong, fatal, cruel, whatever

Comment: the problem is not here m the problem at : 

    printf(" hi : %c\n" , x[i]);

it print nothing , i try this statement that containe strcpy , and it's work!! , the computer print the output correctly !!, please try it to belive , thank you anyway @deviantfan

Comment: Unfortunately one of the nasty features of the C language is that code which is in fact blatantly wrong can still be legal, compile cleanly, and *appear* to work "correctly".  The first 3 lines of your program are such a case.

Comment: Sigh...if you can prove me that you are not overwriting something with this statement, i´ll give you my whole SO reputation.(good idea, haccks). Fact is, all writes to the memory are overwriting something. The problem is, that you´re overwriting stuff which doesn´t belong to the variable x (which has only 1 byte or something like that). Unless argv[1] is empty, strcpy will write at least 2 byte. And if argv[1] is empty, argc would say it doesn´t exist (by the way, you´re not checking argc). edit: This is my last post regarding this statement. If you don´t want to believe, let it be

Comment: What is x[i] in your code?

Comment: i@valter  mean by this , is to print a single character .

Comment: x is not a pointer! `printf(" hi : %c\n" , x);`

Comment: @SuperLearner x is not a pointer so you cannot do x[i] in that way, check my answer for clarification.

Comment: What valter implies, too: This code won´t even compile. So, how do you know that the strcpy "works perfectly"?

Comment: i conclude since ' printf("%s and it's length is %d : \n" , &x , strlen(&x)); '   , worked then this will work .

Comment: @OP: `strcpy(&x,argv[1]);` invokes UB as code is writing outside memory own by `x`.  everything after that is irrelevant.

Comment: @deviantfan i'm not here to challenge you body , we are here to learn and share our knowledge , are we ? . so when i said that's compiled and it have run , but the last printf statement does not give any output , i just tell what happend with me , i'm not lie to just prove that you are wrong !! ,

Comment: @SuperLearner That line does compile BUT it returns junk data (memory) here is my output when I ran it with just 't' as the input:
"to<@ and it's length is 4 :"

Comment: the website prevent me to ask any question any more , what is the work?

Comment: @SuperLearner I don't know what you mean by what is the work but if you run the code that's in my answer then it should work the way you wanted it to work.

Comment: @SuperLearner: You're clobbering memory you don't own; just because it doesn't immediately crash doesn't mean it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, starting from the beginning:

```
int main(int argc ,char *argv[20])
                             ^^^^
```

This does nothing; whenever you declare a function parameter as `T a[N]` or `T a[]`, it's intepreted as `T *a`; the traditional way to write this is as either

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
```

or

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
```

The second case more accurately reflects what's really happening; `argv` is a pointer to a sequence of pointers to `char`.  The value of `argv[argc]` is `NULL`.

```
{
  char x ;
  strcpy(&x,argv[1]);
```

This is a problem; by declaring `x` as `char`, you've only set aside enough storage to hold a single character value<sup>1</sup>, but you're trying to use it to store an *array* of character values; that isn't going to work, and you're going to wind up clobbering whatever memory immediately follows `x`, which may or may not lead to a crash.  C doesn't do any bounds checking for you; when you give `strcpy` an address, it will happily copy the given string to the storage following that address without making sure that storage is valid.

You have two options at this point: you can either declare `x` as an *array* of `char`:

```
  char x[SOME_SIZE]; // where SOME_SIZE is large enough to handle your
                     // largest expected input
```

and use `strcpy` as follows:

```
  strcpy( x, argv[1] );
```

*or* you can simply declare `x` as a pointer to `char`:

```
  char *x;
```

and assign it to point to the beginning of `argv[1]`:

```
  x = argv[1];
```

Either way, the rest of the code becomes

```
  printf("%s and it's length is %d : \n" , x , strlen(x));  // no & before x
  int i ;
  for(i=0 ; i < strlen(x) ; i++)
  {
      printf(" hi : %c\n" , x[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note that a much simpler way of doing this would be

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  char *p = argv[1];
  if ( p )              // argv[1] is not NULL
  {
    while ( *p )        // argv[1][i] is not 0
      printf( "hi: %c\n", *p++ );
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1.  Which is why `x[i]` wasn't working for you, since `x` is not an array or pointer expression</sup>

Comment: that is what i need , every one tell me that it's wrong , but no one tell me  why , that is a very good answer from someone who is dealing with C language from 1990 (before i borne) , but i have a little question , why when i run the code , my code accept to store in  location that it's not mine ?

Comment: @SuperLearner: Because the memory you were overwriting didn't contain anything "important", which was strictly a matter of bad luck.  It could be your implementation allocated more stack space than you needed for a single `char` variable and you wrote into that excess.  It could be you just lucked out and wrote into memory that nothing else was using.

Comment: I would +1 this answer for use of pointers increment but I have to wait for 4 hours.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is correct, but there are some problems in the code.
`x` is only a single character. You´ll need an array of it.
Then replace every `&x` with `x`, because the array pointer itself is already an address.
And another thing: `char *argv[20]`.
Why 20? Why not `char *argv[]` ?

Comment: Grr, you beat me to it, lol. I would +1 this answer but I have reached my max limit for the day.

Comment: but it can work by x (which is single character) , again the problem is when you get the for loop..

Comment: How do you want to store multiple characters in a single one? Just because the program won´t crash immediately, it is not ok to do so.

Answer (score 1):

deviantfan is right that you are overwriting something in memory that does not belong to the variable. Here is one of the ways to accomplish your task without any memory-editing voodoo:

```
#define ARGV_SIZE 20

int main(int argc ,char *argv[ARGV_SIZE])
{
    char x[ARGV_SIZE];
    int argvLength;

    strcpy(x, argv[1]);
    argvLength = strlen(x);
    printf("%s and it's length is %d : \n" , x , argvLength);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < argvLength; i++)
    {
        printf(" hi : %c\n" , x[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

or without the x variable you can do this:

```
int main(int argc ,char *argv[])
{
    int argvLength = strlen(argv[1]);

    printf("%s and it's length is %d : \n" , argv[1] , argvLength);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < argvLength; i++)
    {
        printf(" hi : %c\n" , argv[1][i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the `char x[strlen(argv[1])];` line will work, because array definitions need a size that's known at compile time. `strlen(argv[1])` is not known until run time.

Comment: @RobH You're right, what am I doing? lol. I added the define back since i know that will work, but a better approach will be the 2nd code since it will handle any argv size.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc ,char *argv[20]){
    char y = 'Y';
    char x ;
    char z = 'Z';
    strcpy(&x, "This program is correct!!!");
    printf("%s and it's length is %d : \n" , &x , strlen(&x));

    printf("%c%c%c", x,y,z);//print TYZ ?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just save the first letter into x and overwrite some memory so when you call &x you can retrieve the whole string? OP also wanted to print each character in the string.

Comment: @JohnOdom It is a test program code is either it is a memory overwrite or it wouldn't be normal end. Perhaps correctly it does not work (as in his think).

Comment: No , it's give segmentaion fault in printf statemetn number 2 , and it does not give the value in the printf statement number 1 , thaaaaaank you , i get it !!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY strcpy(&x, "This program is correct!!!"); does memory overwrite. You are using a small string. Try a much bigger one. It will crash.

Comment: @valter Please do what you want it.